# Why lombok, micronaut and querydsl does not work with micronaut in example?

Tags: java, maven, lombok, micronaut

I have this error with @Slfj

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable log
```

Why lombok, micronaut and querydsl does not work with micronaut annotation processor in example?

How to fix this compilation error?

I have latest version of micronaut, lombok, etc.

Here is my pom.xml file part related to compilation maven plugin with querydsl, mapstruct, etc.:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessors>
                        <annotationProcessor>lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                        <annotationProcessor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                        <annotationProcessor>org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                    </annotationProcessors>
                    <!-- Uncomment to enable incremental compilation -->
                    <!-- <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation> -->
                    <annotationProcessorPaths combine.self="override">
                        <path>
                            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
                            <version>1.3.1</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                            <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
                            <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                            <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
                            <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
                            <artifactId>micronaut-data-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${micronaut.data.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>io.micronaut.spring</groupId>
                            <artifactId>micronaut-spring-annotation</artifactId>
                            <version>${micronaut.spring.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>io.micronaut.spring</groupId>
                            <artifactId>micronaut-spring-web-annotation</artifactId>
                            <version>${micronaut.spring.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>io.micronaut.spring</groupId>
                            <artifactId>micronaut-spring-boot</artifactId>
                            <version>${micronaut.spring.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>io.micronaut.security</groupId>
                            <artifactId>micronaut-security-annotations</artifactId>
                            <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--enable-preview</arg>
                        <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=io.x</arg>
                        <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=y</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: +bigger problem "Micronaut Data method is missing compilation time query information. Ensure that the Micronaut Data annotation processors are declared in your build and try again with a clean re-build."

Comment: check your dependencies and read that one: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/#buildConfig 'Micronaut Data and Lombok'